# Can a C++ client call a golang GRPC server stub written in golang?

Tags: c++, go, grpc

Can I write a C++ client to call a GRPC routing written in golang? If possible does it need some kind of redirection, i.e, via a stub in C++ invoking golang function?
or 
Is GRPC agnostic what languages the two end points are implemented in?

Answer (score 5):

Of course, you can have a GRPC server written in golang, and have a client written in C++. The client code only need to depend on the protobuf definition. It doesn't matter whether the server is written in golang, java, c++ or whatever.